# What does the "2 arrows inside a broken triangle" notification icon mean on Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, notification-icons

Since yesterday, I am seeing the below icon on my Samsung Galaxy M30s that looks like 2 arrows inside a broken triangle.

[image]

I have gone through the official user manual and found nothing related to this.

What does this icon mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [data saver](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/what-is-the-data-saver-feature/) 
 icon - switch it off from your settings and it will vanish (Thanks to OP for the link of Data saver)

Source: Personal experience

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to settings and then
Connection >data usage> data saver
and turn off the data saver if you would like to remove the sign
[image]